# Why won't my React Native useState setting update?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state

I have a function:

```
    const [audioState, setAudioState] = useContext(AudioContext)

    const toggleMute = () => {
        console.log('audioState.isMuted', audioState.isMuted)
        setAudioState((s: AudioStateType) => ({ ...s, isMuted: !s.isMuted }))
    }
```

The `console.log` hits, but I don't get the `isMuted` to be toggled out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: useContext doesnt work like that. Just a typo in your question? If you are returning an array we need to see you AudioContext

Comment: You need to ensure that the `AudioContext` provider is wrapping your app somewhere upstream from were you are consuming the conext, and that is indeed is providing a value that is an array of state and setter. Please update answer to include your `AudioContext` component code and more details about the component hierarchy.

Comment: What if you move the console.log directly after the useContext line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have this wrapped in my `AudioProvider`. Once I did that, it worked fine.